/var Size increase
We have two 3TB hard disks and will install a web application server for the mail backup process. We need to allocate more space to the /var partition. How can we achieve this during the installation of Ubuntu 20.04?

Instead of making /var a separate partition, I suggest you make the subdirectory of /var that is going to grow large a separate partition.

Don't use var as a partition :P that method is no longer.  analyze what makes var grow: there are 3 common ones: 1. cups 2. logs 3. mysql 4. apache. The last 2 should put their data on a personal disk outside of the system; 1 you can config to not keep as many old print files. 2: examine the large log and fix either the error or lower the log leve
